# How to get folder size with rsync?

Tags: rsync

I'm wondering if there is a way (a command) that i can use to find the size of rsync address, without starting syncing?

For example how i can find the size of `rsync://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/vim/` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you combine the `-n` flag (dry run or simulate transfer, doesn't actually copy any files) and `--stats` you should be able to find out the total amount of files copied.

Example (simulating two files being copied locally, 445 bytes each):

```
$ rsync -avz -n --stats . ../test/
building file list ... done

Number of files: 14
Number of files transferred: 0
Total file size: 890 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 299
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 315
Total bytes received: 20

sent 315 bytes  received 20 bytes  670.00 bytes/sec
total size is 890  speedup is 2.66
```

(Note the *Total file size* line.)

The official [rsync docs](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html) state in the `--stats` section that

> Total file size is the total sum of all file sizes in the transfer.
>   This does not count any size for directories or special files, but
>   does include the size of symlinks.

You can also consider the `-h` option that outputs numbers in a more human-readable format.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
rsync --info=stats2 -h -r host:directory/
```

remember the trailing slash.

```
-h human-readable
-r recursive
```

the size of the remote directory is printed at the end of the output.

Answer (score 1):

rsync -avvni sourcedir/ destdir/

Broken down that is:

-a archive meta-option
-vv extra verbosity
-n dry run
-i itemize changes

Normally rsync happens between two folders. Using rsync to find the size of changed data between two directories

So we need to supply source and destination directory to find the delta differences.

Ref: http://kristau.net/blog/20/